# Power BI Measure - Consistent value based on the first date

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am currently trying to create a measure that will choose the first total return value based on the earliest date selected. I am using a date slicer and want the value to remain the same throughout the rest of the dates.

Below is example data for one of the fund IDs I have. So if I choose the first date to be 1st of October, I want the value 148 to show throughout the rest of the dates. If I were to choose the first date value to be 4th October, I would want 171 to show.

[image]

Below is my attempt which almost gives me what I want, however it chooses the minimum value based on all data rather than the first value based on date.

`First Total return Value = CALCULATE(FIRSTNONBLANK('table'[Total Return value],MIN('table'[Total Return value])),FILTER(ALL('table'), 'table'[fundid] IN VALUES('table'[fundid])))`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to provide the full dax expression without knowing more about your data model (like do you have a date table etc...).
Regardless - your expression will first need to capture the selected date. Then do an ALL with a filter on that selected date.
Something like:

```
First Total return Value = 
  var selectedDate = FIRSTDATE('table or date table'[dateColumn])
  var result = CALCULATE(
    FIRSTNONBLANK('table'[Total Return value], MIN('table'[Total Return value])),
    FILTER(ALL('table'), 'table'[fundid] IN VALUES('table'[fundid]) && 'table'[dateColumn] = selectedDate )
  )
  RETURN result
```

Hopefully this will get you going.